# Ether price prediction after PoS consensus protocol in Ethereum 2.0

Tags: ether, price, eth-2.0

What do you think about the Ether price after Ethereum 2.0 moves to Proof of Stake consensus protocol?
will it rise or fall? and why?

Answer (score 1):

The price of a cryptocurrency is determined by what people are willing to pay for it. What people are willing to pay for it is determined by what each person believes is the future value of ETH. What each person believes is the future value of ETH is determined by the available information about Ethereum and the rest of the world.

If we now look at your question, will that event change the price? An event that is known to happen can change the price in theory only if

1. It goes better than expected. In that case might be everything happens on-time without any problems.
2. Something goes wrong or there is a delay.

If it just happens like the majority expects, there won't be any price change.

Disclaimer: This assumes all people act rationally and in their own best interests. Obviously human psychology can be quite different from that.

Comment: You're saying that the price of ether will not necessarily change because of Ethereum 2.0 changes, right?. But what about the electricity bills? when people are paying less for the bills while mining Ether, it means ethereum miners may benefit more than bitcoin miners. So more will people mine ethereum instead of other coins. what do you think?

Comment: @Masoudjt that change in the amount of miners should in theory be reflected in the ETH price before the event happens